# Why does this code throw an IndexOutOfBounds error?

Tags: c#, indexoutofboundsexception

When trying to split a list in half, using the GetRange function in C#. When running the below code;

```
Console.WriteLine(cardDeck.Count());
List<card> cardDeckDuplicate = cardDeck.GetRange(0, 26);
Console.WriteLine(cardDeckDuplicate.Count());
List<card> cardDeckDuplicate2 = cardDeck.GetRange(27, cardDeck.Count - 1);
Console.WriteLine(cardDeckDuplicate2.Count());
```

The list I am trying to split is cardDeck, and card is a user-created object. The output to this program is 
52,
26.
Then it throws an out of bounds error.
Can anyone suggest why? It would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `IndexOutOfBounds` exception is thrown when an index of some sort is out of range. In your code, the problem shoud be at the 4th line, where instead of `GetRange(27, cardDeck.Count - 1)` you should probably write `GetRange(27, cardDeckCount - 27)` instead!

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter of [`List<T>.GetRange()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.getrange?view=netframework-4.8) is the **number of elements** you want to extract, not the index of the last element you want.

So this should work:

```
List<card> cardDeckDuplicate2 = cardDeck.GetRange(27, cardDeck.Count - 27); // instead of -1
```